# How to move image data from within a searching window to local memory OpenCL

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, opencl

I've implemented an exhaustive block matching algorithm in parallel using OpenCL and am now trying to optimise the algorithm by moving the searching window to Local memory. The code I have so far is as follows:

```
//loop through whole search space and move to local
    for (int i = -searchWindow-blockSize; i <= searchWindow+blockSize; i++) {
        for (int j = -searchWindow-blockSize; j <= searchWindow+blockSize; j++) {
            tgid = (cache[lid].x + i) + (cache[lid].y + j) * imWidth;
            nlid = (blockSize+searchWindow + i) + (blockSize+searchWindow + j) * ((searchWindow+blockSize) * 2 + 1);

            prevCache[nlid] = prevFrame[tgid]; 
            nextCache[nlid] = nextFrame[tgid];

            barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
        }
    }
```

The nested for loops loop over the searching window and as the image data is 1 dimensional, I need to convert it to a 1D identifier by doing x + y * width to get tgid and nlid. cache[lid] is of type float2 storing the x and y coordinate of the current point of reference for the kernel location in the whole image. lid is the local work item id from get_local_id(0) Therefore, I am fetching the data from the searching window around the point of reference in the whole image and moving it to a local 'prevCache' and 'nextCache' which I can then perform my block matching algorithm on.

The issue I am getting is that the correct data is not always being assigned to the cache. To test this, I made prevCache and nextCache store the same data from only nextFrame like the code below:

```
//loop through whole search space and move to local
    for (int i = -searchWindow-blockSize; i <= searchWindow+blockSize; i++) {
        for (int j = -searchWindow-blockSize; j <= searchWindow+blockSize; j++) {
            tgid = (cache[lid].x + i) + (cache[lid].y + j) * imWidth;
            nlid = (blockSize+searchWindow + i) + (blockSize+searchWindow + j) * ((searchWindow+blockSize) * 2 + 1);

            prevCache[nlid] = nextFrame[tgid]; 
            nextCache[nlid] = nextFrame[tgid];

            barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
        }
    }

    if (prevCache[220] != nextCache[220])
        printf("test");
```

This if statement at the bottom should always be false as prevCache and nextCache should contain the same data, however, when I run the code, 'test' is being printed to the console several times. It seems to me that it is a synchronisation problem or something as when I change cache[lid].x and cache[lid].y to a fixed number, 'test' is never printed, but I have no clue at this point. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

1. Concerning local memory for optimization in general, let me paste something form my thesis here for you to think about:

> Local memory is smaller but faster than global memory. Every compute
>   unit has its own local memory, which is accessible for every
>   processing element within this compute unit. Kernels can trigger a
>   synchronized bulk loading of data from global memory into local
>   memory. This allows for fast and efficient access for the processing
>   elements to that bulk of data. This can under certain conditions prove
>   beneficial for the runtime. Let us assume that the time for bulk
>   loading a chunk of data of size s into local memory, takes t_s time
>   units. Every work unit will have k random access read or write actions
>   within this chunk of data. The time needed for one read / write action
>   to local memory is denoted as t_l and the time needed for one read /
>   write action from global memory cache is denoted as t_g. We assume
>   that the relation t_l < t_g holds. Loading a chunk of global memory
>   into local memory is beneficial to the runtime if the number of read /
>   write actions k is large enough to satisfy:
>
> > k · t_g > t_s + k · t_l

2. In general it is better to use the synchronized bulk-copy operation [async_work_group_copy](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/async_work_group_copy.html) provided by openCL to copy from global to local memory, than to manually copy word by word.
3. Concerning your code and your problem:

Your processing elements in your work unit write to the same slice of local memory but from different points in global memory, effectively overwriting the data. Prove:

If your work group size is at least 2 then there is one element with lid=0 and one with lid=1.

If cache[0].x != cache[1](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/async_work_group_copy.html).x or cache[0].y != cache[1](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/async_work_group_copy.html).y then tgid has a different value for those two processing elements.

Your index nlid is constant for all your processing elements as long as the state of (i,j) synchronized across your processing elements (which you guaranteed with the local memory fence).

4. Finally a note concerning your nested loops.
   If you really want to do it this way, try an approach that reads memory that lies close together in one go. Let's say your image is organized like this:

> ```
>    1    2    3 ...  w
>  w+1  w+2  w+3 ... 2w
> 2w+1 2w+2 2w+3 ... 3w
> ....
> ```

If you wanted to read a 3-by-3 window starting in the left upper corner, you should construct your loop like this

```
for(int row = start_pos.y; row < start_pos.y+3; row++){
   for(int col = start_pos.x; col < start_pos.x+3; col++){
      tmp = data[col+w*row];
   }
   barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
}
```

This way you read in this order 1,2,3,w+1,w+2,w+3,2w+1,2w+2,2w+3

This way openCL would cache global memory, then your processing elements would read 1,2,3 from cache, openCL would cache the next chunk of global memory and your kernel would read the next words and so on.

The way you wrote it it would it would read the data in this order: 1,w+1,2w+1,2,w+2,2w+2,3,w+3,2w+3

For this openCL will again cache global memory, your processing elements read their first data word and openCL would again start to cache after which your your PEs would read their second data word and so on. this would lead to loading the same three chunks of global memory into the global memory cache multiple times when loading each of them once would suffice.